# How to force Ruby release memory to OS

Tags: ruby, memory, release

As the title, I have a ruby program deal with a large term of data. The program took all memory and there is a calling of system command `hostname` in it,
and an error happened

`Cannot allocate memory - hostname`

I've tried `GC.start` and it doesn't work.

So how can I force ruby to release the memory unused?

OK, this is a test code from other people, and the error at last shows that `big_var` has been recycled. However the memory is still not released.

```
require "weakref"
def report
  puts "#{param}:\t\t Memory " + `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`
      .strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1].to_s + 'KB'
end
big_var = ""
#big_var = WeakRef.new(big_var)

report
big_var = 1_000_000.times.map(&:to_s)
report

big_var = WeakRef.new(big_var)

GC.start

sleep 1
report

p big_var.length

#Memory 7508KB
#Memory 61516KB
#Memory 53700KB
#test.rb:20:in `<main>': Invalid Reference - probably recycled (WeakRef::RefError)
```

**OK, I tried things blow and I do not understand why the `GC.stat[:heap_used]` is still that large after I did `$big_var=nil` and `GC.start`**

```
puts GC.stat[:heap_used]
$big_var = []
  5000000.times { |i|
    $big_var << i.to_s
  }
puts GC.stat[:heap_used]
$big_var = nil
puts GC.stat[:heap_used]
GC.start
puts GC.stat[:heap_used]

#70
#12286
#12286
#9847
```

In addition, I use Ruby 2.1 and CentOS 6.4

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html

Comment: show us the code sou

Comment: I've put the test code on and thank you for attention~~

Comment: To make it short: You can't.

Comment: Thank you all. And now I know I can't achieve that thing.

Comment: May be you can patch ruby, it should be not hard

Answer (score 2):

I can see the  garbage-collection is done by [`WeakRef`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html) class as documented. here is my try to prove this :

```
require 'objspace'
require "weakref"

big_var = ""
puts "memory size: #{ObjectSpace.memsize_of big_var}"

big_var = 1_000_000.times.map(&:to_s)
puts "memory size: #{ObjectSpace.memsize_of big_var}"

big_var = WeakRef.new(big_var)
GC.start

puts "memory size: #{ObjectSpace.memsize_of big_var}"
```

**output**

```
[shreyas@arup_ruby (master)]$ ruby a.rb
memory size: 40
memory size: 11636312
memory size: 40
[shreyas@arup_ruby (master)]$
```

Look at the method : [`memsize_of`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of).

Comment: Yes, I can get the same out put even just set big_var to nil. But the memory is still not released~~~

Comment: I think memsize_of is just the size of the memory that big_var is referencing now. But the large memory it referenced before is still holding by Ruby, not released.

Comment: @sou Ok may be.. I'm not sure :/